# How to filter with the WordPress shortcode API in combination with coinmarketcap API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

So I am working with the coinmarketcap api and try to combinate it with WordPress.

In WordPress I am using the following php code:

```
function api() {
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start=0&limit=250';
$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
$name = $api_response[1]["name"];
$usd = $api_response[1]["price_usd"];
echo $name . "<br />";
echo $usd;
}
add_shortcode( 'api_short', 'api' );
```

So this code is working and I get my results on the WordPress page by using the shortcode api_short.

My problem now is that I want to use the shortcode on the following way:

[api short name ="20"]

This way I can switch from data easily by only using the shortcode instead of changing the code the whole time.

The 'name' variable in this case is the name of the cryptocurrency as can be seen here: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start=0&limit=250 . 0 = bitcoin , 1 = ethereum.

I hope someone knows a way to get this working, I tried somethings but so far without a result.

The WordPress shortcode documentation can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

## First:

**Prefix your functions** - especially if you're using a name that's got a global scope or appeal.

`api()` should really be something along the lines of `solaiman_api()` to prevent any conflicts.

## Second:

You should be using the [WP Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache results so you don't rate limit the CMC API

## Third:

For the actual answer to your question, you just need to parameterize the input value in the URL.

```
function solaiman_api( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'placeholder' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $coin  = $atts['coin'] ? $atts['coin'] : 0; // Default to 0 for BTC
    $limit = $atts['limit'] ? $atts['limit'] : 250; // Default to 250

    $url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start='. $coin .'&limit='. $limit;

    $response     = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

    foreach( $api_response as $c ){
        echo $c['name'].': $'.$c['price_usd'].'<br />';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'cmc_api', 'solaiman_api' );
```

Note I changed your function name and the shortcode, since `api_short` isn't terribly descriptive.

This shortcode would now look like this:

```
[cmc_api coin="1" limit="1"]
```

Which should give you just the price of Ethereum.

## Use This Code Instead:

Here's a better one that caches the results for 10 minutes according to CMC's terms of service:

```
function solaiman_api( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'placeholder' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $coin  = $atts['coin'] ? $atts['coin'] : 0; // Default to 0 for BTC
    $limit = $atts['limit'] ? $atts['limit'] : 250; // Default to 250

    $url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start='. $coin .'&limit='. $limit;

    $transient_name = 'cmc_api_'.$coin.'_'.$limit; // One transient per coin per limit

    if( false === ( $response = get_transient( $transient_name ) ) ){
        $response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
        set_transient( $transient_name, $response, 600 ); // Cache for 10 minutes
    }

    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

    foreach( $api_response as $c ){
        echo $c['name'].': $'.$c['price_usd'].'<br />';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'cmc_api', 'solaiman_api' );
```

You can see an example of `[cmc_api coin="1" limit="1"]` here: http://xhynk.com/headless/2018/02/28/cmc-test/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the quick reply! Very much appreciated! Still a bit new to all of this, but glad people like you are over here helping :)